# Google Sheet : how to share individually

Tags: google-apps-script

I have edited a Google Script for a Google Sheet created, where users need to fill in the cells, and then submit. The outputs are shared in a separate sheet.

The thing actually is that when someone is typing answers, the other users see them and cannot edit.

Do you know any function that could be applied in order to prevent users to see inputs in "live"? How can we do, so that each user is individual and can submit their own answers even if there is someone else also filling in their own answers?

Please find below the script used.

````
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1xPkCBdPAc0OOGTsDxSAz7Rx4kYEfqiEUsUCaYXFV-hc");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var inputS = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var outputS = ts.getSheetByName("OUTPUT_Fiche de compta Prof");
  var inputRng = inputS.getRange("A2:K2");
  var values = inputRng.getValues();
  inputRng.clearContent(); // clear input range     
  outputS.getRange(outputS.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}```
````

Comment: I would consider a web app or google form

Comment: What's the procedure to transform the current Google script into a web app?

Comment: Information about web apps is in the guide section of the documentation

Comment: You can also make the users submit Google forms with their input and then calculate the rsults form the form response in the destination spreadsheet.